# When would you use attr_writer?

Tags: ruby, class, object, instance, attr

I can imagine when you want some attribute to be only readable, or be writable and readable, but not when you want an attribute to be writable and not readable.

In some cases, you might want to read some attributes but not be able to change them. For example, if you have an `Animal` class and want to initialize it with a name, age, and color, you could write

```
attr_accessor :age, :color
```

and then for name have

```
attr_reader :name
```

because a name doesn't change. A cat can get older or change color, but the name (for the sake of this question) once assigned should not be changed.

On the other hand, I cannot rationalize a scenario (aside form passwords) where you would need `attr_writer` (as opposed to `attr_accessor` or `attr_reader`). Under what circumstances would you want to write something, but not want to read it? What type of scenario or situation calls for `attr_writer`?

If you can think of a scenario in other programming languages, that is welcome but my immediate scope of Object Orientation knowledge is within Ruby.

Comment: I'd use `attr_writer` if I was providing the getter myself.

Comment: Maybe a little contrived, but for `attr_writer` without a getter, I could imagine a Ruby version of [Bulls and Cows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulls_and_Cows). The game object allows one player to (secretly) set the code via `game.code=`, but does not allow the opponent to easily obtain it via `game.code`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you want a trivial writer and a custom reader? It's common to want to memoize a default value when calling a reader if the `ivar` isn't already set.

```
class Oof
  attr_writer :rab

  def rab
    @rab ||= "rab, of course!"
  end
end

oof = Oof.new
oof.rab # => "rab, of course!"
oof.rab = "zab"
oof.rab # => "zab"
```

Comment: This exactly is the case.

Comment: thanks guys! I talked to one of my instructors about it and he brought up the point about passwords where the user would write them but the programmer wouldn't be able to see it but I will definitely bring up this example with him!

Comment: @M.C. omitting the getter would just makes it less convenient to retrieve the value of an instance variable, but it is still (easily) possible.